# Comment extraction from large amount of .JPG images using Python

Tags: python-3.x, image, metadata

I'm a beginner in Python and need to extract comments I made during fieldwork from a large amount of photos (>1000). They were made with an Iphone and were already converted to .JPG and stored in a single folder.
The info I need is stored in the comments section (screenshot from "Get info" option on a macbook):
[Get info example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L7Nj.png)

I parsed a lot of similar questions here and tried the following code below, but the metadata it returns doesn't include what I need.

Has anybody an idea how I could access the comments and store them in a dataframe/list?

```
from PIL import Image

from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS


# path to the image or video

imagename = ".../IMG_0001.JPG"

# read the image data using PIL

image = Image.open(imagename)

# extract EXIF data

exifdata = image.getexif()

# iterating over all EXIF data fields

for tag_id in exifdata:

    # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id

    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)

    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)

    print(f"{tag:25}: {data}")
```

GPSInfo                  : 2180
ResolutionUnit           : 2
ExifOffset               : 264
Make                     : Apple
Model                    : iPhone SE (2nd generation)
Software                 : 15.3.1
Orientation              : 6
DateTime                 : 2022:04:13 18:44:29
YCbCrPositioning         : 1
XResolution              : 72.0
YResolution              : 72.0
HostComputer             : iPhone SE (2nd generation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you are looking for is probably in the jpeg comment block, which is a different kind of metadata from EXIF data (all EXIF data is Metadata, but not all Metadata is EXIF data).  It is not the best place to put important data because it is a very fragile location, as some programs will overwrite it.  For example, older versions of Photoshop would overwrite it with `File written by Adobe Photoshop #.##`.

A quick search pulls up [this page](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4450#issuecomment-592737056-permalink) which might have the code you need, assuming I picked the correct library (I'm not very knowledgeable about Python).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This is already very helpful. The library is correct and the answers on the page try to solve the same issue. However, at the moment I don't yet manage to extract the comments.
I tried this solution, but it returns a key error for "COM" (or any other string I tried):
```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("comment.jpg")
print(im.app["COM"])  # b'JPEG-COMMENT-TEST\x00'
```
I also tried if the information is included in the output of the .info() function, but I can't change the output to something readable (code from above doesn't work for .info() )

Comment: You might try using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org) to verify exactly where the data you are looking for is located.  Use the command in [Exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) to get all data including duplicates and the groups they belong to.  Unfortunately, I can't help with the Python code.

Comment: Exiftool didn't find it, but it put me on the right track. The data seems to be mac-specific. With the package "osxmetadata" one can obtain the "findercomment" quite easily in Python as a string:
```
import os
import osxmetadata

md = osxmetadata.OSXMetaData(".../IMG_0001.JPG")
md.findercomment
```
This should allow me to extract the data any way I want. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: The Mac specific tags aren't extracted by default.  If you add `-api RequestAll=2` to the command, exiftool will list them.  You can even copy them directly into the file with exiftool.  See the [MacOS tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/MacOS.html) for details.

Comment: MacOS stores its own metadata in the system and not in the image files themselves.